# How to ADD/COPY file from host to Docker image created in the middle of the build (partial log)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm running this example Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

CMD ls /
ADD build.log /root
```

And run the docker build:

```bash
docker build -t test . | tee build.log
```

The goal is to include the build log into the Docker image.

In real project the `build.log` contains thousands of lines. I understand that the buffering occurs and not all the lines will be saved to local file, but that is OK.

The `build.log` in the image is always empty. I have tested both with ADD and COPY command.

Is there a way to include such file, even partially in the Docker image?

Comment: My comment won't help to answer, but _can_ help understand what happens. "The build.log in the image is always empty" is probably because the first step of the `docker build` captures every file in the build context as-is at the time the command is run = the current directory here (this is the line saying `Sending build context to Docker daemon`). Also, since you can't `COPY` or `ADD` a file outside the build context, I'm afraid there is no easy solution. Maybe there is a solution using multi-stage build though but not sure.

Comment: A hacky solution would be to run `docker build` command twice, so that the second one have `build.log` in its context; but I **highly** recommend to **not** apply this solution, as it makes builds non reproducible.

Comment: as with the hen and the egg: egg must always come first.... you cannot include the build log of an docker image into the (very) same image!!! (unless time travels are discovered;)

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
FROM ubuntu:latest AS build
CMD ls /
FROM build AS final
ADD build.log /root
```

And then:

```
docker build --target build . > build.log
docker build --target final .
```